# Python - Using nonces with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using python 2 with requests. This question is more of a curiosity of how I can improve this performance.

The issue now is that I must send a cryptographic signature in the header of the request to a HTTPS server. This signature includes a "nonce" which must be a timestamp, and ALWAYS must increase (on the server side).

Obviously this can wreak havoc on running multiple HTTP sessions on multiple threads. Requests ended up sent out not in order because they get interrupted between generating the headers and sending the HTTPS POST request.

The solution is to lock the thread from before creating the signature till the end of recieving HTTPS data. Ideally, I would like to release the LOCK after the HTTP request was SENT, and not have to wait for the data to be recieved. Is there any way I can release the lock, using requests, after just the HTTP headers are SENT? See code sample:

self.lock is a Threading.Lock. This instance of this class (self) is shared amongst multiple Threads.

```
def get_nonce(self):
    return int(1000*time.time())

def do_post_request(self, endpoint, parameters):
    with self.lock:
        url = self.base + endpoint
        urlpath = endpoint
        parameters['nonce'] = self.get_nonce()
        postdata = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
        message = urlpath + hashlib.sha256(str(parameters['nonce']) + postdata).digest()
        signature = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.secret_key), message, hashlib.sha512)
        headers = {
            'API-Key': self.api_key,
            'API-Sign': base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
        }
        data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
        response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=True).json()

    return response
```

Comment: Can you switch to [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) or maybe [this](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures)?

Comment: Yes, futures looks most promising because it looks light weight, and the example has 2 code points (begin request and finish request). I don't want to have to add more dependencies to the project unless I have to. Also hopefully futures will work with python 2.7 backport.

Comment: Realized these don't solve the problem. I have to make absolutely sure the headers have been sent before I can release the lock... To hack it so far, I've put an artificial delay of 500ms.

Comment: :-(.   Only other suggestion that comes to mind:   Use requests to prepare the request data, but use a vanilla socket to actually send the data / receive the response.  I *think* you could also use requests to parse the response, however, you lose things looks sessions and redirects being automagically handled.  Can you make design changes on the server side?

Comment: No need for sessions or redirect, so I may dive into the requests objects to see if I can find something useful. Monkey patch socket or something.

Comment: Does the nonce have to be incremental? Could you use a UUID or is the server out of your control? Perhaps an atomic counter could offer better performance characteristics?

Comment: divide the problem as producer and consumer. Consumer, the main thread sends the https requests sequentially one by one and the child thread, the producer sequentially  creates the signature. No locking and only two threads. pass the sigs to the consumer via a queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the requests library [doesn't have any support](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking) for sending asynchronously.

> With the default Transport Adapter in place, Requests does not provide any kind of non-blocking IO. The Response.content property will block until the entire response has been downloaded. If you require more granularity, the streaming features of the library (see Streaming Requests) allow you to retrieve smaller quantities of the response at a time. However, these calls will still block.
>
> If you are concerned about the use of blocking IO, there are lots of projects out there that combine Requests with one of Python’s asynchronicity frameworks. Two excellent examples are grequests and requests-futures.

I saw in a comment that you hesitate to add more dependencies, so the only suggestions I have are:

- Add retry logic when your nonce is rejected. This seems like the most pythonic solution, and should work fine as long as the nonce isn't rejected very often.
- Throttle the nonce generator. Hold the timestamp used for the previous nonce, and sleep if it hasn't been long enough when the next nonce is requested.
- Batch the messages. If the protocol allows it, you may find that throughput actually goes up when you add a delay to wait for other messages and send them as a batch.
- Change the server so the nonce values don't have to increase. If you control the server, making the messages independent of each other will give you a much more flexible protocol.
- Use a session pool. I'm guessing that the nonce values only have to increase within a single session. If you create a thread pool and have each thread open its own session, you could still have reasonable throughput without the timing problems you currently have.

Obviously, you'd have to measure the performance results of making these changes.

Even if you do decide to add a dependency that lets you release the lock after sending the headers, you may still find that you occasionally have timing issues. The message packets with the headers could be delayed on their way to the server.

Comment: I don't think the excerpt properly applies. I am using requests in individual threads, so they do run asynchronously. I am effectively looking for an on_progress_downloaded event that I can hook into (like a downloading progress bar functionality). So far seems like feature request.

Comment: If you want to know when the start of the response has been received, @beiller, look at the streaming features mentioned in the excerpt. That means that you'll still have to wait for the response to begin before you can release the lock, though. If the session pool will work, I think that's probably the best option.

Comment: Hi Don, Appreciate your answer. None of your bullet points will work for various reasons however. The session pool will not work because the nonce values have to increase across all sessions. Can't change server. Batching is similar to my lock method. The nonce generator is re-entrant so that won't work. Retry may work but, I get temp banned if too many bad nonces.

Comment: Again thanks for you answer, basically requests wont support what I want per-say. I admit it is a bit specialized. So technically you are right!